# MVC - paging and sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, paging

I am attempting to implement paging and sorting into my Index view. I am following the example at http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/implementing-sorting-and-paging-in-asp.net-mvc.html however my work is neither paging or sorting. I am not sure where I went wrong.

My Index view is passed a parameter when accessed so I did modify it a little however it should not have cause it to do nothing.

My PagingInfo viewModel used for the paging and sorting is as followings.

```
public class PagingInfo
{
    public string SortField { get; set; }
    public string SortDirection { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }
}
```

My controller has

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        DeviceLogIndex vm = new DeviceLogIndex();

        var devicelogs = db.DeviceLogs
            .Include(d => d.Device)
            .Include(d => d.DeviceLogType)
            .Include(d => d.Device.ManufacturerModel)
            .Where(d => d.DeviceID == id);
        { 
            PagingInfo info = new PagingInfo();
                info.SortField = "DeviceLog";
                info.SortDirection = "ascending";
                info.PageSize = 4;
                info.PageCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)(db.DeviceLogs.Count()/info.PageSize)));
               // info.PageCount +=1;
                info.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
                var query = devicelogs.OrderBy(c => c.DeviceLogID).Take(info.PageSize);
                ViewBag.PagingInfo = info;

                vm.DeviceLogs = query.ToList();

                Device model = db.Devices.Find(id);
                model.DeviceID= id;
                vm.MyDeviceID = id;


                return View(vm);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(PagingInfo info, int id)
    {
        DeviceLogIndex vm = new DeviceLogIndex();

        var devicelogs = db.DeviceLogs
            .Include(d => d.Device)
            .Include(d => d.DeviceLogType)
            .Include(d => d.Device.ManufacturerModel)
            .Where(d => d.DeviceID == id);
        {
            IQueryable<DeviceLog> query = null;
            switch (info.SortField)
            {
                case "EntryDate":
                    query = (info.SortDirection == "ascending" ?
                        devicelogs.OrderBy(c => c.EntryDate) :
                        devicelogs.OrderByDescending(c => c.EntryDate));
                    break;
                case "LogType":
                    query = (info.SortDirection == "ascending" ?
                         devicelogs.OrderBy(c => c.DeviceLogType) :
                         devicelogs.OrderByDescending(c => c.DeviceLogType));
                    break;
            }

            query = query.Skip(info.CurrentPageIndex * info.PageSize).Take(info.PageSize);
            ViewBag.PagingInfo = info;

            vm.MyDeviceID = id;

            vm.DeviceLogs = query.ToList();
            return View(vm);
        }
    }
```

And my View contains these parts

```
@model AQB_MON.ViewModels.DeviceLogIndex
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".header").click(function (evt) {
        var sortfield = $(evt.target).data("sortfield");
        if ($("#SortField").val() == sortfield) {
            if ($("#SortDirection").val() == "ascending") {
                $("#SortDirection").val("descending");
            }
            else {
                $("#SortDirection").val("ascending");
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#SortField").val(sortfield);
            $("#SortDirection").val("ascending");
        }
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("form").submit();
    });

    $(".pager").click(function (evt) {
        var pageindex = $(evt.target).data("pageindex");
        $("#CurrentPageIndex").val(pageindex);
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("form").submit();
    });
});
</script>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
   @{
    AQB_MON.ViewModels.PagingInfo info = ViewBag.PagingInfo;
  }

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { id = Model.MyDeviceID})
</p>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DeviceLog", FormMethod.Get))
{
   @Html.Hidden("SortField",        info.SortField)
   @Html.Hidden("SortDirection",    info.SortDirection)
   @Html.Hidden("PageCount",        info.PageCount)
   @Html.Hidden("PageSize",         info.PageSize)
   @Html.Hidden("CurrentPageIndex", info.CurrentPageIndex)
```

to set the Headers that are sortable -

```
<th>
        <a href="#" data-sortfield="LogType"
           class="header">Device Log Type</a>
    </th>
 <th>
        <a href="#" data-sortfield="EntryDate"
           class="header">Entry Date</a>
    </th>
```

for the paging -

```
  <td>
       @for (var i = 0; i < info.PageCount; i++)
    {
        if (i == info.CurrentPageIndex)
        {
            <span>@(i + 1)</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <a href="#" data-pageindex="@i"
               class="pager">@(i + 1)</a>
        }
    }
    </td>
```

It's a lot of code that does not seem to do anything. Just confused.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `Index(PagingInfo info, int id)` and see what `info.CurrentPageIndex` is set to when the method is called. You may be getting a default value (0).

Comment: it doesn't seem to get the [HttpPost] ActionResult Index. It just keeps going to the regular Index that set the info.CurrentPageIndex = 0.

Comment: Ok, next step: set a breakpoint (in the browser debug tool) in your ` $(".pager").click(function (evt) ` function, and make sure that's the one being called. Also look in the network panel (again in the browser) or use Fiddler to see the URL that's used when you click the submit button. Somehow, either your CurrentPageIndex value isn't being passed, the submit button is acting as a normal submit and not calling the JS handler, or your MVC route is incorrect. There's not a lot else that can go wrong here.

Comment: Also, `#CurrentPageIndex`? Normally I'd expect this to be a route parameter, not a bookmark. Which is what `#` means.

Comment: I believe the CurrentPageIndex value is not being passed. It looks like it is a constant 0